# assign value with stochastic function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, stochastic

I'm trying to STOCHASTICALLY assign a fourth value (1 of 2 types of buddy) based on value of category value.

small df with randomly assigned values for 3 features: category, age and sex

```
        Unique_ID   Category    Age      Sex        Buddy  
0       0           2           11       male       NaN
1       1           3           7        female     NaN
2       2           1           4        male       NaN
3       3           2           20       male       NaN
4       4           1           19       female     NaN
```

i include code to generate df if helpful for answer

i've made a function to  hard-coding the probabilities for np.random.choice, but am running into error message when applying assign_buddy function to df
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
columns = ['Unique_ID',  'Category', 'Age', 'Sex', 'Buddy']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

Sexes = ['female', 'male']
df.Sex = np.random.choice(a=Sexes, size=n, p=[0.6, 0.4])

list_Category = [1,2,3,4]
df.Category = np.random.choice(a=list_category, size=n, p=[0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1])

buddy_list = ['buddy_1', 'buddy_2']

def assign_buddy(Category_prob_list):
"""
takes in a Category value
return: Buddy
"""    
    if  df['Category'] == list_Category[0]:
        df['Buddy'] = np.random.choice(a=buddy_list, size=n, p=[0.1, 0.9])
        return df['Buddy']
    elif df['Category'] == list_Category[1]:
        df['Buddy'] = np.random.choice(a=buddy_list, size=n, p=[0.3, 0.7])
        return df['Buddy']
    elif df['Category'] == list_Category[2]:
        df['Buddy'] = np.random.choice(a=buddy_list, size=n, p=[0.7, 0.3])
        return df['Buddy']
    elif df['Category'] == list_Category[3]:
        df['Buddy'] = np.random.choice(a=buddy_list, size=n, p=[0.9, 0.1])
        return df['Buddy']
    else:
        pass
# should apply assign_buddy to each row in df
df['Category'].apply((assign_buddy))
```

i have a dictionary of probabilities for assign_buddy, but can  not figure  out the map and apply logic despite all the documentation .

i've tried creating a function that returns probabilities from d to be passed to the argument p in np.random.choice, but it's not working.

```
# key is category label and values are probabilities for np.random.choice
d = {1: [0.1, 0.9], 2: [0.3, 0.7], 3: [0.7, 0.3], 4: [0.9, 0.1]}
```

any insight appreciated!

Comment: Can you help me understand how you're performing this assignment? What is a Buddy? Describe, at a high level, the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: sure.  looking to learn how to define a function to stochastically assign values to a synthetic data set.  looking to insert values stochastically to test if analysis tests are robust and reflect different inputs.     likewise, dictionary of probabilities was created with assumptions that will change once further info (from separate files) is incorporated.

Comment: trying to learn how to stochastically assign values in a synthetic data set.  need to insert values stochastically to test if analysis tests are robust and reflect different inputs.  dict of probabilities created with assumptions that will change once further info (from separate files) is incorporated. a 'buddy' is a placeholder for a generic assigned attribute.  i am ultimately looking to learn object oriented approach to model populations, but this step at least gets me to outputting a sample dataset to learn stats tests.  @coldspeed really appreciate your attention and this forum!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
n = 20
columns = ['Unique_ID',  'Category', 'Age', 'Sex', 'Buddy']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

list_category = [1,2,3,4]
buddy_list = ['buddy_1', 'buddy_2']
Sexes = ['female', 'male']
df.Sex = np.random.choice(a=Sexes, size=n, p=[0.6, 0.4])
df.Category = np.random.choice(list_category, size=n, p=[0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1])

d = {1: [0.1, 0.9], 2: [0.3, 0.7], 3: [0.7, 0.3], 4: [0.9, 0.1]}

for val in list_category:
    sz = (df["Category"] == val).sum() # find the size for array to create
    # use `loc` to select places you want to replace
    df.loc[df["Category"] == val,'Buddy'] = np.random.choice(
                                               buddy_list, sz, p=d[val])
```

Comment: still not sure how apply function but the     (anticipating the list_category will change) but really appreciate your help.  df["Category"] == val,'Buddy' filter did the trick.  thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. glad it helps.